# make random forest with fitness function and genetic algorithm

Tags: r, random-forest, fitness

I would like to set up a random forest for my fitness function using a genetic algorithm, like they do with weights in neural networks...
But it's quite difficult for me to figure out what exactly I need to change in the `rf` model

```
set.seed(123)
X <- matrix(rnorm(1000),ncol = 5)
Y <- rnorm(nrow(X))
library(randomForest)
rf <- randomForest(Y~.,X,ntree=50)
```

I guess I need to change something in `rf$forest$...` but what exactly I am not very clear about.
Can someone explain to me what exactly I need to change in order to change the model and adjust it for my fitness function

Comment: Genetic algorithms are used for optimization and random forests for regression and classification.  A fitness function should be fully defined from the data, so I'm not sure how you see random forest playing a role.

Comment: neural network weights can be optimized by a genetic algorithm, neural networks are used for classification and regression. I don't understand where you see the problem?